# Show that $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}=\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

How could we show that $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}=\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$, where $a \in \mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ is of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ ??

Could you give me some hints??

Comment: I'm assuming you mean isomorphic and not equal, right?

Comment: This is usually how I think of $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ in the first place. What are your definitions for $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ be a field with four elements (call it $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ if you want). Observe that $K$ contains $0$, $1$, and two other elements that we will call $a$ and $b$.

Observe that $1+1=0$. Indeed, the subgroup of $(K,+)$ generated by $1$ has to have order that divides $4$, so either $1$, $2$ or $4$. And $1$ is not possible since $1\not=0$, and $4$ is not possible otherwise $2\cdot 2=0$.

Hence, $K$ contains $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$ as a subfield.

You can then check that $1+0=1$, $1+1=0$, so $1+a=b$ and $1+b=a$.

Observe then that $a^2\not=1$, because otherwise $(a+1)^2=0$. We also have $a^2\not=a$, as $a\notin\{0,1\}$. This implies that $a^2=b$.

Hence, $a^2=a+1$, so $a^2+a+1=0$. This yields $K=\mathbb{F}_2[a]/(a^2+a+1)$.

Comment: How do we know that $0$ and $1$ are elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$?? 
$$$$
Does it stand that $\mathbb{F}_2=\mathbb{Z}_2$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar The field axioms demand that any field has two distinguished elements, $0$ and $1$ (which aren't equal).

Comment: Exactly. And usually, $\mathbb{F}_n$ denotes a (the) field with $n$ elements. One can show that $n$ is a power of a prime number and that there is only one such field, up to isomorphism. The proof is given above, when $n=4$.

Comment: @JérémyBlanc I got stuck right now... To show that the fields are isomorphic do we show that they contain the same elements??

Comment: You need to show that there is a bijection between the fields, which is compatible with products and sums (isomorphism, or bijective homomorphism). The proof above shows that there is only one possibility for a field of $4$ elements, as we send $0$ onto $0$, $1$ onto $1$ and then get two other elements and see that you have no choice for the products and sums.

Answer (score 1):

This might help, depending on the definition you're using: $\mathbb Z_2$ is a field and $\mathbb F_{2^2}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Z_2$. What is its dimension?

Comment: #$\mathbb{F}_{2^2}=2^2$ and #$\mathbb{Z}_2=2$, right??

Answer (score 1):

There's only one irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ over $\mathbf F_2$, namely `$x^2+x+1$`, hence only one quadratic extension of $\mathbf F_2$. Moreover, over any field, an extension of prime degree is necessarily simple.

Comment: How do we know that $x^2+x+1$ is the only irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar There are only 4 distinct degree two polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2$: $x^2 + x + 1$, $x^2$, $x^2 + 1$, and $x^2 + x$, and the rest have roots.

Comment: There are not so many polynomials of degree $2$ over $\mathbf F_2$: $x^2+x+1, x^2$ and $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$. *Added*: @Stahl is right: I forgot $x^2+x$.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_2$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, right??

Comment: Yes . It's standard  to denote the finite field with $q=p^n$ elements $\mathbb F_q$, or $\mathbf F_q$ in old style maths.

Comment: And for many people, $\Bbb Z_p$ does not mean $\Bbb Z/(p)$ but the ring of $p$-adic integers.

Comment: Including me. However, in general, the context is clear.